# How to use output redirection in powershell's command-measure?

Tags: powershell, time, cmd

How to use output redirection in powershell's command-measure?

I want something similar to `time` from Linux, a simple program to time how long a program runs

I thought this would work, but the std out doesn't redirect: `Measure-Command {start-process python printstuff.py > Output.txt -Wait}`

Example Input:

```
Measure-Command {echo hi}
```

Example Output:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 1318
TotalDays         : 1.52546296296296E-09
TotalHours        : 3.66111111111111E-08
TotalMinutes      : 2.19666666666667E-06
TotalSeconds      : 0.0001318
TotalMilliseconds : 0.1318
```

Comment: Use the -redirectstandardoutput  Parameter of start-process

Comment: You could also just add `-PassThru` on `Start-Process` in the existing example and that should work. `Start-Process` doesn't generate any output on std out unless prompted.

Comment: Why use Start-Process in the first place?  Just execute `python printstuff.py > Output.txt`

Comment: Thanks @KeithHill! (are you tagged? - I don't see the @ changing) I thought start process was a necessary piece of Measure-Command. I found some excellent documentation here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Start-Process` doesn't write to standard output. Instead it creates a new console window and runs the process with its standard output set to the console window. Using the redirection operator will redirect stdout for Start-Process but as it doesn't write to stdout you get an empty file.

The solution is to use the `-RedirectStandardOutput` option to tell `Start-Process` to redirect stdout for the process it started.

```
Measure-Command { Start-Process python printstuff.py -RedirectStandardOutput output.txt -Wait }
```

Note that if you want to pass any options to the python program you will have to specify `-ArgumentList` explicitly:

```
Measure-Command { Start-Process python -ArgumentList ('printstuff.py','-opt') -RedirectStandardOutput output.txt -Wait }
```

The messiness of `-ArgumentList` means that unless you really do need to use Start-Process you will probably find it easier just to drop it and then the redirection works normally:

```
Measure-Command { python printstuff.py >output.txt }
```

Note that if you want to quote the name of the executable (or use a value in a variable) you will need to use the call operator (I mention this as I wonder whether this is why you were looking at Start-Process in the first place):

```
Measure-Command { & "C:\Python34\python" printstuff.py >output.txt }
```